# Access to 'my filters' and 'create a filter' from Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, tag-filters

This is available over at stackexchange.com under "Filtered Questions" but seems weird for someone who's only using Stack Overflow. Some links from the 'User Name' drop down (the one in header up top) would be helpful.

There [used to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115242/155160) a link to tag subscriptions on the sidebar, but it looks like it's been removed at some point and even when it existed, it still sent me to stackexchange.com.

So, to reiterate, it would be nice to have a link to this somewhere from my profile/settings. It seems less than ideal (UX-wise) to force folks over to Stack Exchange to define a filter, since many folks only interact with Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry again about the "new question" advice. I edited this one to bump it and get some fresh eyes on it. I personally think we need to redo a lot of our tag filtering stuff. It's not as useful and accessible as it could or should be.

Comment: Yah I agree.  (And on a meta-meta-level, it seems unfortunate (unfair?) that you removed your comment below (giving me questionable advice), but my question that I created has to stick.  Live and learn, I guess.)

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. My comment is still there, and I deleted your new question before editing this one.

Comment: Weird. You comment is now back.  And my question is gone as you said.  Hm...anyway, I'm happy!